# Creating endless scrolling mountains for a music video

Tags: modeling, objects, compositing-nodes, video

I'm trying to make a music video with a camera endlessly moving past snowy mountains but I'm not sure how to make it look half decent. I've watched a few tutorials on using the ANT landscape generator but that's usually for a couple mountains, and even with the "large landscape" preset I'm not sure if it's big enough to create the illusion of infinite mountains.

Is there a way to do with array modifiers and maybe automatically generate another terrain landscape object once the previous once has moved past the camera's frustum? Is that just an over complicated way of approaching it and would it just be better to swap/cut between clips of the same terrain but from different angles? I'm open to anything.

Comment: You might try this: Mimic the way ANT makes the landscapes, using noise textures, and then animate the coordinates of the noise texture so the mountains move. This might result in a bit of a crawling effect, but it would be infinite. If you use material displacement with cycles rather than a displacement modifier, you can also control the appearance of snow and such so it looks correct.

Comment: Even if you do use a displacement modifier, if you can get the same shape of noise texture in the material you can still do snow that way, or even at least animate a texture for looking like rocks so that it follows the mountains.